# Symfony 5: Argument #1 ($Genre) must be of type ?App\Entity\MusicGenre, string given , called in PartiturasFixtures.php

Tags: string, symfony, object, fixtures

I have installed the orm-fixtures in Symfony 5 and it workes very nice with my entities. But one Entity (**Partituras** = Music scores) has a relationship to the MusicGenre Entity (@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\MusicGenre", inversedBy="musicscore").

So when I try to run the following command: `./bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

the terminal gives me back the following error:

> App\Entity\MusicGenre::setGenre(): Argument #1 ($Genre) must be of type ?App\Entity\MusicGenre, string given, called in /Users/webdevelopment/Sites/creativeStage/src/DataFixtures/PartiturasFixtures.php on line 36

The code in my PartiturasFixtures.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Partituras;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class PartiturasFixtures extends Fixture
{

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {

        // DEFINE AN ARRAY AND INSERT INTO THE DATABASE ALL MUSIC SCORES
        $partituras = array(
            array('id' => '1',
                'genre_id' => '10',
                'cancion' => 'Nova Flor',
                'compositor' => 'Mario Zán e Palmeira',
                'tonalidad' => 'MI mayor | FA mayor',
                'disponibilidad_guitarra' => 'disponible',
                'disponibilidad_arpa' => 'disponible',
                'country_code' => 'BR')
        );

        // END ARRAY

        // CREATE A FOREACH LOOP
        foreach ($partituras as $element):

            $partituraNew = new Partituras();
            $genre_id = $element['genre_id'];
            $cancion = $element['cancion'];
            $compositor = $element['compositor'];
            $tonalidad = $element['tonalidad'];
            $disponibilidad_guitarra = $element['disponibilidad_guitarra'];
            $disponibilidad_arpa = $element['disponibilidad_arpa'];
            $country_code = $element['country_code'];

            $partituraNew->setCancion($cancion)
                ->setGenre($genre_id)
                ->setCompositor($compositor)
                ->setTonalidad($tonalidad)
                ->setDisponibilidadGuitarra($disponibilidad_guitarra)
                ->setDisponibilidadArpa($disponibilidad_arpa)
                ->setCountryCode($country_code)

            // PREPARE DATA FOR THE DATABASE
            $manager->persist($partituraNew);

        endforeach;

        // INSERT DATA INTO THE DATABASE
        $manager->flush();
```

And in the "Partituras" ENTITY the setGenre Method looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\MusicGenre", inversedBy="musicscore")
 */
private $Genre;

public function setGenre(?MusicGenre $Genre): self
{
    $this->Genre = $Genre;

    return $this;
}
```

I know that instead of passing a **string** I have to pass an **object** from the Fixtures to the Entity, do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: ->setGenre(new App\Entity\MusicGenre()); ?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If your `setGenre` method expects an object or null, you cannot pass an integer

Comment: Yes, that´s true I decided to re-write my PartiturasFixtures code and pass an object.

Answer (score 1):

Using an ORM you have to think in terms of objects, not in terms of ids.

`MusicGenre` and `Partituras` here are two classes that represent objects, actors in your domain model. The IDs are just a way to refer to them.

In this case, you have to create a new `MusicGenre` object which is related to more than one `Partituras`, so you need a `MusicGenreFixture` class that creates and persists some `MusicGenre` objects.

You can find all the information you need in the documentation (https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures#sharing-objects-between-fixtures).
As you can see, you can share objects between fixtures and set the fixtures dependencies to load them in order.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to re-write the code for my PartiturtasFixtures and now it is working correctly:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\MusicGenre;
use App\Entity\Partituras;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class PartiturasFixtures extends Fixture
{

    private static function getPartiturasData()
    {
        // DEFINE AN ARRAY TO INSERT INTO THE DATABASE ALL MUSIC TITLES
        yield [
            'id' => '1',
            'musicGenre' => 'Polca paraguaya',
            'cancion' => 'A Juliana',
            'compositor' => 'Diosnel Chase y Dario Gómez Serrato',
            'tonalidad' => 'La menor | Re menor',
            'disponibilidad_guitarra' => 'disponible',
            'disponibilidad_arpa' => 'disponible',
            'country_code' => 'PY'
        ];


    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {

        // DEFINE THE MUSIC GENRE TYPE
        $musicGenre1 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre1->setName('Baião');
        $musicGenre2 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre2->setName('Carnavalito');
        $musicGenre3 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre3->setName('Chamamé');
        $musicGenre4 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre4->setName('Cumbia');
        $musicGenre5 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre5->setName('Danzante');
        $musicGenre6 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre6->setName('Guarania');
        $musicGenre7 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre7->setName('Joropo');
        $musicGenre8 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre8->setName('Pasacalle');
        $musicGenre9 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre9->setName('Polca correntina');
        $musicGenre10 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre10->setName('Polca paraguaya');
        $musicGenre11 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre11->setName('Rasqueado');
        $musicGenre12 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre12->setName('Rasguido doble');
        $musicGenre13 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre13->setName('San juanito');
        $musicGenre14 = new MusicGenre();
        $musicGenre14->setName('Zamba argentina');

        // PREPARE MUSIC GENRE DATA FOR DATABASE
        $manager->persist($musicGenre1);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre2);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre3);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre4);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre5);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre6);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre7);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre8);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre9);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre10);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre11);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre12);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre13);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre14);

        // DEFINE ONE MUSIC-GENRE DATA ARRAY ...
        $musicGenres = [
            'Baião' => $musicGenre1,
            'Carnavalito' => $musicGenre2,
            'Chamamé' => $musicGenre3,
            'Cumbia' => $musicGenre4,
            'Danzante' => $musicGenre5,
            'Guarania' => $musicGenre6,
            'Joropo' => $musicGenre7,
            'Pasacalle' => $musicGenre8,
            'Polca correntina' => $musicGenre9,
            'Polca paraguaya' => $musicGenre10,
            'Rasqueado' => $musicGenre11,
            'Rasguido doble' => $musicGenre12,
            'San Juanito' => $musicGenre13,
            'Zamba argentina' => $musicGenre14
        ];

        // END ARRAY

        // CREATE A FOREACH LOOP
        foreach (self::getPartiturasData() as $partiturasData):

            $musicScores = new Partituras();
            $musicScores->setCancion($partiturasData['cancion'])
                ->setGenre($musicGenres[$partiturasData['musicGenre']])
                ->setCompositor($partiturasData['compositor'])
                ->setTonalidad($partiturasData['tonalidad'])
                ->setDisponibilidadGuitarra($partiturasData['disponibilidad_guitarra'])
                ->setDisponibilidadArpa($partiturasData['disponibilidad_arpa'])
                ->setCountryCode($partiturasData['country_code'])
                ->setGuitarUrl($partiturasData['guitar_url'])
                ->setHarpUrl($partiturasData['harp_url']);

            // PREPARE DATA FOR THE DATABASE
            $manager->persist($musicScores);

        endforeach;

        // INSERT DATA INTO THE DATABASE USING THE FLUSH METHOD
        $manager->flush();

    }
}
```